# Apache en Windows y certificados de Certbot que se corrompen

Tags: php, python, apache, xampp, windows10

Tengo Apache en Windows. Y descargaba los certificados de ZeroSSL que me siguen funcionando perfectamente bajo las directivas siguientes.

```
VirtualHost _default_:443>  
    ServerAdmin propr@icloud.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/wpen"
    ServerName    ejemplo.com
    ServerAlias    ejemplo.com
    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile "C:/xampp/apache/conf/ssl.crt/pr.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:/xampp/apache/conf/ssl.key/pr.key"
    SSLCertificateChainFile "C:/xampp/apache/conf/ssl.ca_/ca_pr.crt"
    ErrorLog "logs/ejemplo.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/ejemplo.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

pero con Certbot los certificados generados son  .PEM y los configuro asi.

```html
<VirtualHost _default_:443>  
    ServerAdmin propr@icloud.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/wpen"
    ServerName   ejemplo.com
    ServerAlias  ejemplo.com
    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile "C:\Certbot\live\ejemplo.com/fullchain.pem"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:\Certbot\live\ejemplo.com/privkey.pem"
    ErrorLog "logs/ejemplo.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "ejemplo.com-access.log" common
 </VirtualHost>
```

Y FUNCIONA. PARO Y ENCIENDO APACHE UNA Y OTRA VEZ Y TODO FUNCIONA CORRECTAMENTE.

Ahora bien, reinicio el equipo y todos los certificados .PEM se corrompen y Apache no arranca.
Quito del arranque los hospitales .PEM y todo vuelve a funcionar.

Hago certificados nuevos y se repite la historia. Solo los .PEM son los que me causan el problema.

¿Porque?
Alguien me puede ayudar